# Flash Camera Crash

Tags: android, flash, camera

my app uses the camera flash but I do not understand why if I open another app and then resume my app the app crashes. I think because I have not inserted the pause and resume in the app.

This is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//flag to detect flash is on or off
    private boolean isLighOn = false;

    private Camera camera;

    private Button button;

    private LinearLayout rl;

    int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);
        rl=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        rl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black)); 


        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (isLighOn) {

                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isLighOn = false;
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);

                    rl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black)); 

                } else {

                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isLighOn = true;
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);

                    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);

                }

            }
        });

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-29 21:24:51.048: D/AndroidRuntime(27113): Shutting down VM
03-29 21:24:51.048: W/dalvikvm(27113): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418eeda0)
03-29 21:24:51.058: E/AndroidRuntime(27113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 21:24:51.058: E/AndroidRuntime(27113): Process: com.example.torcia, PID: 27113
03-29 21:24:51.058: E/AndroidRuntime(27113): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
```

Comment: The stack trace of the crash would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you let your app go into the background, stop() is called.  Then you release your camera.  After this you cannot use it again-  you need to call camera.open() and get a new camera object.  I suggest not creating camera objects in onCreate, but only doing it in onStart (or onResume).

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you release the camera when the application is stopped, but you don't initialise the camera again when the application is resumed. Your camera initialisation code is in onCreate which won't get called again.

It's probably best to initialise the camera in onResume and release it in onPause.

E.g.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    camera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Edited answer with example

Comment: It crashes as soon as I launch the app

Comment: `03-29 21:41:15.529: W/dalvikvm(28898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418eeda0)
03-29 21:41:15.549: E/AndroidRuntime(28898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 21:41:15.549: E/AndroidRuntime(28898): Process: com.example.torcia, PID: 28898
03-29 21:41:15.549: E/AndroidRuntime(28898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.torcia/com.example.torcia.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`

Comment: An app I worked on recently has a custom camera implementation and follows this kind of logic. This is a trivialised example, but it's based on the usage described in the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Comment: If you're opening the camera in onCreate, this might be the reason, you will need to remove it from onCreate and move the other logic into onResume.